# Path to report in .net Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, c#-3.0

I have a crystal report in the root directory of the .Net Windows service application. If it is a web application I specify something like below

```
 rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("myReport.rpt"));
```

How do I need to specify if it is a windows service?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

When your hosting a windows service, the current directory can sometimes be tricky to obtain.